# fillna string/object only

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use fillna with a pandas dataframe, but for 'object' dtypes only.

I believe the following works, but would like to avoid using concat if not needed.

```py
import pandas as pd

new_df = pd.concat([df.select_dtypes(exclude='object'),
                    df.select_dtypes('object').fillna('')], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

using [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df[:]=np.where(df.dtypes=='object',df.fillna(''),df) #this will assign to same df
```

To create a new df:

```
new_df=df.copy()
new_df[:]=np.where(df.dtypes=='object',df.fillna(''),df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.loc`:

```
new_df = df.loc[:, df.dtypes == object].fillna('')
```